# Создание поиска на сайте

Tags: php, mysql

Как я вижу работу поиска.
Пользователь вводит запрос, который обрабатывается (отрезаются окончания, слишком короткие слова, символы...). А потом ищутся совпадения с этой строкой в таблице, где для каждой странице сайта, создана запись.

Трудность в том, как создать записи в таблице. Т.е. как php скрипту залезть на страницу сайта и проиндексировать ее (отобрал определенные слова убрал повторения).

Я так понимаю, что скрипту нужен не код страницы, а только та информация, которая видна пользователям.

Раз уж все зашли в тупик уточню вопросы:

1. Как заставить скрипт зайти на каждую страницу сайта?
2. Как выдрать со страницы только видимый пользователю контент?

Comment: А как у вас информация на страницах хранится? Прямо в html-фалйах?

Тогда можно их парсить, но на это будет куча времени уходить. Придется какой-нибудь алгоритм кэширования придумать.

Либо переделать сайт и контент хранить в БД, тогда можно будет использовать поиск по БД, либо что-то типа SPHINX'a

Comment: Сайт хранится в БД. Но очень разбросанно, там нет таблицы "СТРАНИЦЫ". В том то и беда.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда - то очень давно бредил мечтою создать свой поисковик, но времени не было, однако что - то сделал.

Как мой робот - индексатор работал :

1. Взять ссылку из базы, открыть страницу.
2. Найти на этой странице все ссылки с помощью регулярного выражения.
3. Записать эту странице целиком в базу данных.
4. Каждый уровень прохода должен быть пронумерован, этот уровень был 1-м.
5. Получить следующую ссылку из базы(самую первую, что нашли на первой странице) и открыть её.
6. Найти все ссылки на этой странице, записать страницу в базу, это 2-й уровень.
7. Получить ссылку из базы со страницы 1-ого уровня
8. и т.д.

Не думаю, что всё понятно, но это достаточно лёгкий алгоритм.

Вот так ищем ссылки :

```
preg_match_all('#<a.*?href="(.+?)".*?>(.+?)</a>#is', $html_document, $links, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Т.к. такой сценарий - робот будет работать очень долго (от 2 - х минут до 2 - х часов), нужно в самом начале воткнуть строчки :

```
set_time_limit(0);//отключить ограничение на время работы сценария
ignore_user_abort(1);//продолжать работать, если закрыта сессия(вы закрыли в обозревателе эту страницу)
```

Искать в базе можно следующим образом :

```
SELECT * FROM sites WHERE html_content LIKE = '%поисковый%запрос%'
```

Будьте осторожны, здесь нет защиты от инъекций, это пример.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Примерно так я и думал. Единственное, что я бы изменил для универсальности поисковика, это первый пункт. Ведь так мы можем искать, только если нам известна база данных, пароль, таблица и т.д. А что если сначала брать главную страницу сайта, искать все ссылки, сохранять в таблицу. Переходить по всем ссылкам, фиксируя факт перехода (т.е. не ходить два раза по одной ссылке) опять искать все ссылки на новой странице и т.д. Так, заодно, и карту сайта составить можно.

Comment: Согласен, об этом я забыл упомянуть, всегда пожалуйста)

Answer (score 3):

Если всё очень разбросано, то предлагаю воспользоваться библиотекой `Zend_Search_Lucene` (`ZendSearch\Lucene` в zf2). Очень интересная вещь в плане функциональности, к тому-же имеет достаточно неплохое быстродействие (при разумных объёмах индекса).

Сначала создаётся индекс. Заполнять его можно различными способами - если у вас, например, блог, то можно просто пройтись по всем записям из таблицы постов и каждую из них занести в индекс. Если же у вас сайт с более сложной структурой, то можно написать себе простого "паука", который пойдётся по вашему сайту и проиндексирует его, как будто это GoogleBot или Yandex. Для облегчения задачи, в `Lucene_Document_Html` есть метод `getLinks()`, который вернёт все ссылки в документе.

При поиске можно задавать поля поиска (автор, заголовок и прочее), использовать операторы запросов, включать-исключать слова, подсвечивать найденное в результатах поиска и т.д.

Ссылки:

- [Creating a Search Index with `Zend_Search_Lucene`](http://www.larryullman.com/2010/10/27/creating-a-search-index-with-zend_search_lucene/)
- [Yii: Делаем поиск по сайту, используя Zend Lucene](http://loco.ru/materials/247-yii-search-using-zend-lucene)
- [Официальная документация](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ru/zend.search.lucene.html)

Comment: Хорошее решение, но мне бы хотелось понять самому, как это делать.